# How to create an up to date ML recovery?

Tags: macos, usb, recovery

There were several updates affecting the recovery partition. Is there a way to create an usb memory stick containing an up to date Mountain Lion recovery partition?

Comment: You could also use [SuperDuper](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) to have a bootable back-up. I know this isn't the question but it helped me massively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

Download [Mountain Lion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mountain_Lion) again from the [App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/dk/app/os-x-mountain-lion/id537386512?mt=12) and create a bootable USB from the new downloaded files.

Either by using Disk Utility or by using [Lion Disk Maker](http://liondiskmaker.com).

[image]

> **Full tutorial** [can be found on Arstechnica website](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/07/how-to-create-a-bootable-backup-mountain-lion-install-disk/)

Comment: This is not exactly what I wanted, but good enough. I'd like to have just a recovery partition not the entire installation.

Comment: I just figured out how to do that. If you mount InstallESD.dmg you find a hidden BaseSystem.dmg which contains a recovery partition. You might want to burn this to a CD and boot from that.